# Qt Рисование(отображение) множества графических объектов

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Задача простая. Необходимо отрисовать бэкграунд в виде карты( возможно масштабирование карты - приближение/удаление) и так же необходимо размещать объекты которые меняют свое местоположение во времени. Информация на карте должна обновляться по заданному времени с периодом от секунды и выше. Какими инструментами лучше всего воспользоваться?

Comment: Нашел в установке пакета Qt пример "minimal map" который использует QT += location а также 
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
Но знаний по использованию QtQuick нет. Можно ли прикрутить к такому проекту обычный код Qt c++ чтобы поместить объекты на такую карту?

Comment: QWidgets и QtQuick.Window по нормальному не смешиваются, лучше даже не начинать

Comment: Ничего не понял

Comment: Qt представляет собой два API, старый на базе QWidgets и новый - изобретение нокии QtQuick, нельзя в одной программе пользоваться и тем и другим. Я решил что слова" обычный код Qt c++" означают QWidgets